# How to avoid problem with encode UTF-8 error

Tags: python, file

I've got problem with reading text files. When I start program and add file, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/graf_menu.py", line 38, in <module>
    main_func()
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/graf_menu.py", line 32, in main_func
    read_file()
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/graf_menu.py", line 15, in read_file
    for i in f.read():
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 19: invalid start byte
```

In my code there is a line with "encoding="UTF-8". How to solve the problem. The code below:

```
files = input("File name: ")
    try:
        with open(files,"r",encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            for i in f.read():
                print(i,end='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("FileNotFoundError")
```

Comment: what if you don't use the encoding?

Comment: It looks like the file is not UTF-8. Use a different encoding.

Comment: When I dont use encoding it doesn't print out polish letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the program itself. You are getting this error because you are trying to read a file which is not encoded as UTF-8 as UTF-8-encoded. You have to either convert the contents of the file to UTF-8 or specify a different encoding (the one that the file actually uses) in the call to `open`.

Comment: When I try to read files with text I copied from internet it reads perfectly but when I write sth to file manualy and try to read file it throws this error

Comment: Open the file in hex editor and check. Python exception is telling you the exact position of the offending byte sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This file is not encoded as `UTF-8` try to use `encoded="iso-8859-1"`